# Linkedin Api V2 - how to get member country if i am using r_liteprofile + r_emailaddress

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using **r_liteprofile** + **r_emailaddress** permission for V2
I want Linkedin member country

I know that is available in  **r_basicprofile** and to use this I have to take permission from Linkedin

any other option to get Linkedin member country ?

Comment: I don't know why @Linkedin not added member country information in V2  r_liteprofile.
They don't know member country information is basic info and important member name ?

Comment: No reply from Linkedin or they are still working on V2 ?

Comment: Still waiting for solution : for now i have fixed my problem : Taking client Ip then from IP address i am getting country,  also apply to linked for accessing r_basicprofile for country ( better solution is they must add member country information in r_liteprofile )

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Not the way you did with `r_basicprofile` anyway. In the name of user privacy LinkedIn significantly reduced what you can get from the version 2 of their API.

This is the list of attributes returned by `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`:

- id
- firstName
- lastName
- maidenName
- profilePicture

The closest you can get from a country code is the `preferredLocale` key contained in each of the attributes mentioned above. for example, this is what I get from a GET request to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`:

```
{
    "id": "LJRFbGPB_V",
    "lastName": {
        "localized": {
            "pt_BR": "Vincent"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "BR",
            "language": "pt"
        }
    },
    "firstName": {
        "localized": {
            "pt_BR": "Gabriel"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "BR",
            "language": "pt"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if you really need to retrieve the information LinkedIn provided in v1 with `r_basicprofile`, you can [apply to a LinkedIn Partner Program](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs).

You can further check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/lite-profile?context=linkedin/consumer/context).